# JQuery Variable Overwrite In Loop, Want To Retain Different Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, loops

I'm creating a video gallery and have 6 thumbnails that when clicked on, will play the respective video in an iframe on the page.

These 6 thumbnails change when the user goes to the next page of videos, loading the new links which are stored in an XML document.

```
var linkhtml=x[i].getElementsByTagName("linkhtml")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I loop through 6 elements from the XML and change the thumbnail `<td id="videoBox[1-6]">` as such:

```
$('#videoBox' + j).mousedown(function () {
    frames['videoPlayer'].playVideo(linkhtml, videoPlaylist);
});
```

This doesn't work, however, as when I click on any of the thumbnails, it calls on whatever linkhtml was last set to, so the 6th video on the page.

How can I get each thumbnail to retain its link properly?

Comment: There isn't really enough code here for anyone to understand what you're currently doing.  What is `x[i]` a reference to?  As far as I can tell, you're always setting linkhtml to one value, and always asking for that one value in your mousedown.  Can you edit this question to include a more complete listing of all of the related code?

Comment: sorry i can see how it could be a bit confusing. @Guffa got it though and solved it. thanks for your time Ryan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anonymous function to create a closure that captures the value of the variable at that time:

```
(function(linkhtml){

  $('#videoBox' + j).mousedown(function () {
    frames['videoPlayer'].playVideo(linkhtml, videoPlaylist);
  });

})(linkhtml);
```

Comment: you sir, are an absolute genius. works perfectly, however i do not quite understand all of it (jquery syntax wise) so I have some reading to do. thank you very much Guffa :D

Comment: one quick question though: what is the best way to clear this out before loading a new one when switching video pages? simply doing mousedown(function(){}); doesn't seem to be doing the trick

Comment: @DougieBear: jQuery can handle multiple event handlers, so binding another event won't replace the previous one (as when using DOM evements directly). Use the `unbind` method to remove an event binding.

Comment: For anyone looking at this post in the future, I put: `$('#videoBox' + j + 'td').unbind('mousedown', this.onMouseDown);` per Guffa's suggestion above the function and it did the trick. Thanks again.